# warning"No Launcher activity found, The launch will only sync the application package on the device"

Tags: android, android-widget, android-manifest

I'm making an android widget, but I got this warning from console when running my application on emulator

No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.analogclock.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver 
            android:name=".AnalogClockWidget"
            android:label="@string/app_name"  />

        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

            </intent-filter>

             <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/appwidget" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What's the reason? Please give me a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is normal as your widget does indeed not have any activity!

I am guessing you are using the Run or Debug button on Eclipse.
In this case the Run button cannot add your widget to the home screen for you, so it only install the package and give you this warning.

Check that your widget appears in the chooser, when you try to add a widget on the home screen. If it does, then it is working as expected :)

EDIT: try with this manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.analogclock.android"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0"
     >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver 
            android:name=".AnalogClockWidget"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />  
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/appwidget" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I can't find my widget in my widget list, I just  find it in Manage apps.(I assumed " the chooser " means widget list on emulator

Comment: I think you need to export your receiver so it is visible to the Android system. Also your intent-filter and meta-data should be in the receiver element